# Exporting crystal report to pdf

Tags: vb.net

I want to know about how to export crystal report with 4 parameters by code. and  i tried the following code and "invalid index error' is returned.

```
Dim crParameterFieldDefinitions As ParameterFieldDefinitions
        Dim crParameterFieldDefinition As ParameterFieldDefinition
        Dim crParameterValues As New ParameterValues
        Dim crParameterDiscreteValue As New ParameterDiscreteValue
        Dim crParamenter_array As New ParamArrayAttribute
        Dim cryRpt As New ReportDocument
        Dim DefaultPrinterName As String
        Dim oPS As New System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings
        Dim sFilePath As String
        Dim sPath As String
        Dim sFileLoc As String
        Dim sFileName As String
        Try
            sPath = Path.GetTempPath()
            DefaultPrinterName = oPS.PrinterName
            sFilePath = GetCrystalReport(_REPRT_CODE)
            sFileLoc = sPath + "Reports\" + _REPRT_CODE + ".rpt"
            If sFilePath = String.Empty OrElse sFilePath = Nothing Then
                TNotification.StatusBarError("File Not Found.")
                Return False
            Else
                cryRpt.Load(sFileLoc)
            End If
            If Not SetDbLogonInfo(cryRpt) Then
                TNotification.StatusBarError("Database Login Failed.")
                Return False
            Else
                crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = _empid
                crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = _month
                crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = _parea
                crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = _year

                crParameterFieldDefinitions = cryRpt.DataDefinition.ParameterFields
                crParameterFieldDefinition = crParameterFieldDefinitions.Item("empid")
                crParameterFieldDefinition = crParameterFieldDefinitions.Item("month")
                crParameterFieldDefinition = crParameterFieldDefinitions.Item("parea")
                crParameterFieldDefinition = crParameterFieldDefinitions.Item("year")

                crParameterValues = crParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues
                '   crParameterValues.Clear()
                crParameterValues.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue)
                crParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues)
                cryRpt.PrintOptions.PrinterName = DefaultPrinterName
                Dim rep As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FieldObject = Nothing
                'sending report to the printer
                'cryRpt.PrintToPrinter(_noOfCpys, False, 1, 100)
                Dim CrExportOptions As ExportOptions
                Dim CrDiskFileDestinationOptions As New  _
                DiskFileDestinationOptions()
                Dim CrFormatTypeOptions As New PdfRtfWordFormatOptions()
                ' CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = "c:\" + _rptCode + "_" + _docEntry + ".pdf"
                'sFileName = "\\B1devsrv\b1_shr\Attachments\" + _rptCode + "_" + _docEntry.ToString + ".pdf"
                sFileName = TSQL.GetSingleRecord("Select AttachPath  from OADP").ToString.Trim + _empid + "_payslip.pdf"
                CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = sFileName
                CrExportOptions = cryRpt.ExportOptions
                With CrExportOptions
                    .ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile
                    .ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat
                    .DestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDestinationOptions
                    .FormatOptions = CrFormatTypeOptions

                End With
                cryRpt.Export()
                If SendMail(_empid.ToString, sFileName) Then
                    TNotification.MessageBox("Email Sent")
                End If

                If File.Exists(sFileLoc) Then
                    '  File.Delete(strFileLoc)
                End If
            End If
            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try
```

Comment: Where do you get the error? What is the line, stakctrace?

Comment: crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = _empid
                crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = _month
                crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = _parea
                crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = _year

                crParameterFieldDefinitions = cryRpt.DataDefinition.ParameterFields
                crParameterFieldDefinition = crParameterFieldDefinitions.Item("empid")

Comment: Is it on this line? crParameterFieldDefinition = crParameterFieldDefinitions.Item("empid")

Comment: at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.FieldsClass.get_Item(Int32 Index)
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ParameterFieldDefinitions.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ParameterFieldDefinitions.get_Item(String fieldName)
   at GeneralPayrollsln.Button__PSLIPMAIL__btn_send.ConvertToPDF(String _empid, String _month, String _year, String _parea, String _DBPWD, String _REPRT_CODE) in D:\GeneralPayrollfor Integration\Payroll Final 28-11-2012\General Payroll Solution Finilized\GeneralPayrollsln\Button__PSLIPMAIL__btn_send.vb:line 201

Comment: Yes, that would seem to be at crParameterFieldDefinition = crParameterFieldDefinitions.Item("empid") . That would meen that crParameterFieldDefinitions collection does not contain an item by the name of empid. Ensure that your spelling is correct, and that the collection contains the fields in question. Add a watch to crParameterFieldDefinitions and see what is in the collection and what the field names are.

Comment: hi, you are correct ..but now the error is 'The types of the parameter field and parameter field current values are not compatible.' How can i set the 4 parameters.. i got this error at the point crParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues)

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this:

```
       cryRpt.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, False,"ExportedReport")
```